# Общий timeline и независимые события в C#

Tags: c#, моделирование

Извините за дурацкое название: ничего лучше придумать не смог. Мне нужно разработать программу, которая будет имитировать некую линию времени (не совпадающую с реальной, естественно), например, с помощью главного цикла, где каждая итерация будет секундой этой имитационной линии времени (как "тик" в игровых движках); также будут происходить события в разные моменты имитационного времени, событий будет много, во время выполнения программы могут появляться новые, и они должны обрабатываться параллельно.
Скажем, есть очередь, куда могут "записываться" элементы, и обработчик, где они обрабатываются (неожиданно). Если очередь полная, то элемент вернёт `false`, иначе попадёт в очередь и будет ждать обработки всех впереди стоящих. Суть в том, что всё это должно происходить параллельно, а я не могу представить нормальную реализацию. Сейчас мысли лишь о монструозном массиве, куда будут записываться события и тайм-код, а в главном цикле будет проверка, типа такого (псевдокод):

```
for (int i = 1; i < renderTime; i++) {
    switch (eventLine[i]) {
        case "addItem":
            foo();
        case "finalizeItem":
            bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему всё должно реально происходить параллельно? Пусть это будет параллельно в искусственном таймлайне, а в реальности вы можете делать как вам вздумается. Выбираете момент времени, выбираете все события, относящиеся к этому моменту времени, выполняете их, ищете следующий (ближайший) момент времени, повторяете до исчерпания очереди.

Comment: @VladD, то есть вы предлагаете действительно реализовать массив вида `действие => таймкод` и идти по нему?

Comment: Наоборот, таймкод -> действие. И держать отсортированным по таймкоду.

Answer (score 1):

- По моему тут намек на TaskFactory. И асинхронность работы и контроль за колличеством потоков рабочих.
- Или вообще юзать Task-и из коробки, повзоляя самой системе определять колличество в ThradPool-e живых нитей. И собственно ваша работа на тик - к примеру Task(()=> doworkIteration1());
- Только обязательно почитай насчет Task, async,await и с чем их едят.